# Javascript: Using changing global variables in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am working on `Javascript` and using **firefox scratchpad** for executing it. I have a global index which I want to fetch inside my `setTimeout` (or any function executed asynchronously). I can't use `Array.push` as the order of data must remain as if it is executed sequentially. Here is my code:-

```
function Demo() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.counter = 0;
    this.setMember = function() {
        var self = this;

        for(; this.counter < 10; this.counter++){
            var index = this.counter;
            setTimeout(function(){
                self.arr[index] = 'I am John!';
            }, 100);
        }
    };
    this.logMember = function() {
        console.log(this.arr);
    };
}

var d = new Demo();
d.setMember();

setTimeout(function(){
    d.logMember();
}, 1000);
```

Here, I wanted my `d.arr` to have 0 - 9 indexes, all having `'I am John!'`, but only 9th index is having `'I am John!'`. I thought, saving `this.counter` into `index` local variable will take a snapshot of `this.counter`. Can anybody please help me understand whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem in this case has to do with scoping in JS.
Since there is no block scope, it's basically equivalent to

```
this.setMember = function() {
    var self = this;
    var index;

    for(; this.counter < 10; this.counter++){
        index = this.counter;
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.arr[index] = 'I am John!';
        }, 100);
    }
};
```

Of course, since the assignment is asynchronous, the loop will run to completion, setting index to 9. Then the function will execute 10 times after 100ms.

There are several ways you can do this:

1. IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression) + closure

   ```
   this.setMember = function() {
       var self = this;
       var index;

       for(; this.counter < 10; this.counter++){
           index = this.counter;
           setTimeout((function (i) {
               return function(){
                   self.arr[i] = 'I am John!';
               }
           })(index), 100);
       }
   };
   ```

   Here we create an anonymous function, immediately call it with the index, which then returns a function which will do the assignment. The current value of `index` is saved as `i` in the closure scope and the assignment is correct
2. Similar to 1 but using a separate method

   ```
   this.createAssignmentCallback = function (index) {
       var self = this;
       return function () {
            self.arr[index] = 'I am John!';
       };
   };

   this.setMember = function() {
       var self = this;
       var index;

       for(; this.counter < 10; this.counter++){
           index = this.counter;
           setTimeout(this.createAssignmentCallback(index), 100);
       }
   };
   ```
3. Using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

   ```
   this.setMember = function() {
       for(; this.counter < 10; this.counter++){
           setTimeout(function(i){
               this.arr[i] = 'I am John!';
           }.bind(this, this.counter), 100);
       }
   };
   ```

   Since all we care about is getting the right kind of `i` into the function, we can make use of the second argument of `bind`, which partially applies a function to make sure it will be called with the current index later. We can also get rid of the `self = this` line since we can directly bind the `this` value of the function called. We can of course also get rid of the index variable and use `this.counter` directly, making it even more concise.

Personally I think the third solution is the best.
It's short, elegant, and does exactly what we need.
Everything else is more a hack to accomplish things the language did not support at the time.
Since we have `bind`, there is no better way to solve this.

Comment: What if I have 2 parameters (which I am not supposed to pass) other than index? For example: `function(result, status)`. How can we use bind then?

Comment: You basically use it like `Function.prototype.call`. So you'd do `fn.bind(context, firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam)` etc.

Answer (score 5):

The `setTimeout` doesn't have a snapshot of `index` as you are expecting. All of the timeouts will see the index as the final iteration because your loop completes before the timeouts fire. You can wrap it in a closure and pass index in, which means the index in the closure is protected from any changes to the global `index`.

```
(function(index){
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.arr[index] = 'I am John!';
    }, 100);
})(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that by the time settimeout is started, the for loop is finished executing the index value is 9 so all the timers are basically setting the arr[9].

Answer (score -2):

The previous answer is correct but the source code provided is wrong,  there is a mistyping elf in place of self . The solutions works.

An other way , without a closure , is to just add the index parameter to the function declaration in the setTimeout statement

```
function Demo() {
    this.arr = new Array();
    this.counter = 0;
    this.setMember = function() {
        var self = this;

        for(; this.counter < 10; this.counter++){
            var index = this.counter;
            setTimeout(function(){
                self.arr[index] = 'I am John!';
            }(index), 100);
        }
    };
    this.logMember = function() {
        console.log(this.arr);
    };
}

var d = new Demo();
d.setMember();

setTimeout(function(){
    d.logMember();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is incorrect and does not work. You will invoke the function directly, not after 100 ms. You will pass it an argument but it will be thrown away. Then `index` is taken from the outer scope, which is fine because it executes synchronously. Then after 100ms nothing happens.

Comment: If you cut-paste the code in the firefow scratchpad , it's display 9th I'am john, which is the initial question. I just want to help for the mistype.